# How to modify a scatter points plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

i am working on a python script to produce a scatter points plot.
Now, i would like to do some slight modifications, Here is the actual code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})

#Read datafile
Datafile='t_20_12.data'
name=[]
mean=[]
stdvar=[]
with open(Datafile,'r') as ins:
    for line in ins:
        line=line.strip('\n')
        ind=line.index(' ')
        name.append(line[0:ind])
        while line[ind]==' ': ind+=1
        line=line[ind:]
        ind=line.index(' ')
        mean.append(line[0:ind])
        while line[ind]==' ': ind+=1
        line=line[ind:]
        stdvar.append(line)

original_name=['BASAL_INFEROSEPTAL','BASAL_INFERIOR','BASAL_INFEROLATERAL','BASAL_ANTEROLATERAL','BASAL_ANTERIOR','BASAL_ANTEROSEPTAL','MID_INFEROSEPTAL','MID_INFERIOR','MID_INFEROLATERAL','MID_ANTEROLATERAL','MID_ANTERIOR','MID_ANTEROSEPTAL','APICAL_INFERIOR','APICAL_LATERAL','APICAL_ANTERIOR','APICAL_SEPTAL']
short_name=['BasInfSep','BasInf','BasInfLat','BasAntLat','BasAnt','BasAntSep','MidInfSep','MidInf','MidInfLat','MidAntLat','MidAnt','MidAntSep','ApexInf','ApexLat','ApexAnt','ApexSep']

for i in range(len(name)):
    origin=name[i]
    ind=origin.index('_')
    variable=origin[0:ind+1]
    segment=origin[ind+1:]
    modif_seg=short_name[original_name.index(segment)]
    name[i]=variable+modif_seg

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(mean,stdvar)
for i, txt in enumerate(name):
    if (float(mean[i])>1e-4):
        ax.annotate(txt, (mean[i], stdvar[i]))

plt.title('Sensitivity analysis: time')
plt.xlabel('Mean')
plt.ylabel('Standard variation')
plt.show()
```

And Here the datafile

```
a_BASAL_INFEROSEPTAL    0.000127547    0.000142708
b_BASAL_INFEROSEPTAL    5.47966e-05    0.000109593
e_BASAL_INFEROSEPTAL    0.000168496    0.000211819
XI_BASAL_INFEROSEPTAL    6.91457e-05    0.000138291
a_BASAL_INFERIOR    0.000133961    0.00013912
b_BASAL_INFERIOR    0    0
e_BASAL_INFERIOR    0    0
XI_BASAL_INFERIOR    0    0
a_BASAL_INFEROLATERAL    2.41402e-05    4.82804e-05
b_BASAL_INFEROLATERAL    0    0
e_BASAL_INFEROLATERAL    1.0847e-05    2.16941e-05
XI_BASAL_INFEROLATERAL    1.10378e-05    2.20757e-05
a_BASAL_ANTEROLATERAL    0.00014744    0.00029488
b_BASAL_ANTEROLATERAL    0    0
e_BASAL_ANTEROLATERAL    1.32931e-05    2.65863e-05
XI_BASAL_ANTEROLATERAL    0    0
a_BASAL_ANTERIOR    0.000115112    0.000230223
b_BASAL_ANTERIOR    1.0847e-05    2.16941e-05
e_BASAL_ANTERIOR    0    0
XI_BASAL_ANTERIOR    4.92837e-05    9.85674e-05
a_BASAL_ANTEROSEPTAL    0.000395227    0.000156225
b_BASAL_ANTEROSEPTAL    0.000110388    0.000194361
e_BASAL_ANTEROSEPTAL    6.46093e-05    0.000129219
XI_BASAL_ANTEROSEPTAL    6.68646e-05    0.000103741
a_MID_INFEROSEPTAL    9.81276e-06    1.96255e-05
b_MID_INFEROSEPTAL    0    0
e_MID_INFEROSEPTAL    0    0
XI_MID_INFEROSEPTAL    0.000181976    0.000149634
a_MID_INFERIOR    5.31215e-05    0.000106243
b_MID_INFERIOR    0    0
e_MID_INFERIOR    0    0
XI_MID_INFERIOR    6.07881e-05    0.000121576
a_MID_INFEROLATERAL    7.77117e-05    0.000130014
b_MID_INFEROLATERAL    0    0
e_MID_INFEROLATERAL    1.32931e-05    2.65863e-05
XI_MID_INFEROLATERAL    0.000121497    0.000242994
a_MID_ANTEROLATERAL    1.0847e-05    2.16941e-05
b_MID_ANTEROLATERAL    0.000115112    0.000230223
e_MID_ANTEROLATERAL    0    0
XI_MID_ANTEROLATERAL    0    0
a_MID_ANTERIOR    0.000136149    0.000142746
b_MID_ANTERIOR    0    0
e_MID_ANTERIOR    0    0
XI_MID_ANTERIOR    0    0
a_MID_ANTEROSEPTAL    0.000177225    0.00020393
b_MID_ANTEROSEPTAL    6.68646e-05    0.000133729
e_MID_ANTEROSEPTAL    0    0
XI_MID_ANTEROSEPTAL    6.29343e-05    0.000125869
a_APICAL_INFERIOR    0    0
b_APICAL_INFERIOR    6.92841e-05    0.000108435
e_APICAL_INFERIOR    0    0
XI_APICAL_INFERIOR    6.68646e-05    0.000133729
a_APICAL_LATERAL    0    0
b_APICAL_LATERAL    0    0
e_APICAL_LATERAL    0    0
XI_APICAL_LATERAL    0    0
a_APICAL_ANTERIOR    3.90355e-05    7.8071e-05
b_APICAL_ANTERIOR    0    0
e_APICAL_ANTERIOR    5.91207e-05    0.000118241
XI_APICAL_ANTERIOR    9.93506e-05    0.000198701
a_APICAL_SEPTAL    6.68646e-05    0.000133729
b_APICAL_SEPTAL    1.10378e-05    2.20757e-05
e_APICAL_SEPTAL    0    0
XI_APICAL_SEPTAL    9.93506e-05    0.000198701
```

It produce the following Picture:
[Scatter points plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh5dg.png)

This is what i would like to modify:

-Change the font size of the label (txt in annotate function) I tried to look at the options available for annotate so maybe the answer is to do something about txt instead (i will look into it)
=>All right, it seems matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22}) will do the job. Solved and code updated

-The point and the associated label are too close to each other, is it possible to change that?
=>I have found a way to do it, by using

```
    offset_x=str(float(mean[i])+0.00001)
    ax.annotate(txt, (mean[i], stdvar[i]),(offset_x, stdvar[i]))
```

Is there a better/cleaner way?

-Enable a given label to be either at the left or the right of the point it is associated to to make the graph more readable. There might be a way to do so by using the offset_x defined in the previous question but if you have a better idea...

Of course, i will continue to look for an answer on my own and i will update my code if i do.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Usually you would ask a question at the point where you're *really* stuck, meaning that you will not find a solution within the next half an hour by yourself. This would also help to reduce the question to a single well scoped problem. Here it seems you're just not yet completely satisfied with your result, so the obvious is to keep trying until you are either happy with it, or in need actual help.

Comment: You have a point. When i actually posted the questions, i realized several minutes after i could obtained several results on my own and that i was not stucked, indeed. 
I was slightly in a hurry so i misjudged/misevaluated the situation

Only the last question remains but i could just adjust the offset manually and i would be able to get what i want for a specific set of data.

Now, my original questions became "is there a better, proper and/or cleaner way to do that". I see what you mean, i will follow your advice, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xytext details in Matplotlibs Annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928011/xytext-details-in-matplotlibs-annotate)