# How do you offset text in a scatter plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, data-visualization, matplotlib

I've annotated two specific points in my PCA but the text is in the middle of a bunch of points and hard to read. I would like to move it down (and add arrows which I think I've already done succesfully). Can anyone help?

I've made the text in the following way:

```
for i, txt in enumerate(cluster_center_names):
    plt.annotate(txt,(x_cluster_center[i],y_cluster_center[i]), weight="bold", fontsize=10, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='black'))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xytext details in Matplotlibs Annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928011/xytext-details-in-matplotlibs-annotate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`xytext=(x,y)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) to set the coordinates of the text. You can provide these coordinates in absolute values (in data, axes, or figure coordinates), or in relative position using [`textcoords="offset points"`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) for example.

More example at the [annotation tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/tutorials/text/annotations.html)

```
x1,y1 = 0,0
x2,y2 = 20,50
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x1,y1)
ax.annotate("Annotation",
            xy=(x1, y1), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(x2, y2), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='black')
            )
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic

Comment: When I try to use "offset points" with text annotations I'm getting this error:

ValueError: xycoords cannot be an offset coordinate